# listview is not updating with notifydataSetChanged

Tags: android, listview, notifydatasetchanged

My listview is not updating itself with the data that is retrieved after the first 20 items.

I checked multiple times if the data was not passed with json, but it is, only the listview is not updating itself with the added data.

here is my part of code:

```
@Override
public void onGetData(JSONObject obj) {
    Serie[] seriesList;
    if (obj != null) {
        if (pageNumber == 1) {
            series = Serie.serieListFromJSON(this, JsonHandling
                    .getInstance().getJSONArraySerieFromUrlTMDB(obj));
            seriesList = series.toArray(new Serie[series.size()]);
            adapter = new SearchCustomAdapter(this, seriesList);
            lvSearch = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSearch);
            lvSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
            lvSearch.setOnScrollListener(this);
        } else { 
            try {
                Toast.makeText(this, "obj is ?"+obj.toString(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //adapter.clear(); getting an unsupportedmethod exeption
            series.addAll(Serie.serieListFromJSON(this, JsonHandling
                    .getInstance().getJSONArraySerieFromUrlTMDB(obj)));
            seriesList = series.toArray(new Serie[series.size()]);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "obj is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Serie serie = new Serie("not found", "");
        seriesList = new Serie[series.size()];
        seriesList[0] = serie;
        adapter = new SearchCustomAdapter(this, seriesList);
        lvSearch = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSearch);
        lvSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        this.currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
        this.currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
        this.currentTotalItemcount=totalItemCount;  
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    this.currentScrollState = scrollState;

    if(( currentFirstVisibleItem+currentVisibleItemCount) == currentTotalItemcount){
        this.isScrollCompleted();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

 }

private void isScrollCompleted() {
    if (this.currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && this.currentScrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        pageNumber++;
        JsonHandling.getInstance().getJSONFromUrl(tvTitel.getText().toString(), tvYear.getText().toString(), iof, pageNumber);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

}

So could anyone please tell me what i did wrong or missed?

edit:
added the code adjust ments in onscrollStateChange. Still not sure why it should be there and not on get data though.

also here is per requested the searchcustumAdapter :

```
public class SearchCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Serie> {

private final Context context;
private final Serie[] values;

public SearchCustomAdapter(Context context, Serie[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.search_row_layout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null)
    {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_row_layout,
            parent, false);

    TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.SearchRowTitle);
    TextView textViewYear = (TextView) rowView
            .findViewById(R.id.SearchRowYear);
    textViewTitle.setText(values[position].getTitle());
    textViewYear.setText(values[position].getYear());


    return rowView;  
    }
    else
    {
        TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.SearchRowTitle);
        TextView textViewYear = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.SearchRowYear);

        textViewTitle.setText(values[position].getTitle());
        textViewYear.setText(values[position].getYear());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

UPDATE 2:
changed the code on onScrollCompleted to have this part of code:

```
            pageNumber++;
        JsonHandling.getInstance().getJSONFromUrl(tvTitel.getText().toString(), tvYear.getText().toString(), iof, pageNumber);
        series.addAll(Serie.serieListFromJSON(this, JsonHandling.getInstance().getJSONArraySerieFromUrlTMDB(obj)));                 
        seriesList = series.toArray(new Serie[series.size()]);        
        lvSearch.setAdapter(new SearchCustomAdapter(this, seriesList));
```

this does work, but this should not be the way... right?

Comment: So does any1 know a way to fix the problem, as now its not a very good way to do it i believe.(with setting a new adapter).

Answer (score 0):

In

```
onScrollStateChanged method you are notifying list view but not changing its data
```

So try to call

```
onGetData(JSONObject obj) in onscroll it may help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know JSon, so you might have to tweak the code below. On method isScrollCompleted, need to add code similar to:

```
series.addAll(JsonHandling.getInstance().getJSONFromUrl(tvTitel.getText().toString(), tvYear.getText().toString(), iof, pageNumber));                 
seriesList = series.toArray(new Serie[series.size()]);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note: The Array object `seriesList` needs a higher-level scope in the class, not just in `onGetData()`.

Comment: Why should the adding be in the scroll listener and not at the onGetData where i get the data?

and with higher level scoop you mean it needs to be set not on onGetdata but on creation of the activity? it is.(edit: nm it is in the method)

Comment: Let me understand, what triggers onGetData? Is it from JsonHandling.getInstance? If so, you can call onGetData passing the correct obj from isScrollCompleted(), an aspect of polymorphism.

Comment: I would recommend to declare seriesList in the class, outside the method. When it is declared in onGetData(), I am worried data in that object may be cleared because the JVM thinks you no longer need it when it is out of scope of the method onGetData. I am not sure of this aspect mainly because onGetData is protected.

Comment: JsonHandling.getInstance().getJSONFromUrl( returns void

 public void getJSONFromUrl(String titel, String year, IOnFinish listener, int pageNumber) {
  JsonHandlingTMDBAsync task = new JsonHandlingTMDBAsync(titel, year, listener, pageNumber);
  task.execute();
 }

and on the async it will give the data to onGetData with onPostExecute

Comment: `JsonHandling.getInstance().getJSONFromUrl(tvTitel.getText().toString(), tvYear.getText().toString(), iof, pageNumber);
      series.addAll(Serie.serieListFromJSON(this, JsonHandling.getInstance().getJSONArraySerieFromUrlTMDB(obj)));                 
      seriesList = series.toArray(new Serie[series.size()]);
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
Did it like this, but still same, no update and i do get the toast with page 2 and up with all the data(in onGetData).

Comment: cc2k, It seems there is progress, that's encouraging. Perhaps it's a good time to post the code in SearchCustomAdapter, especially in getView(). And include the constructor of the adapter too since seriesList is passed through it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74295/discussion-between-cc2k-and-the-original-android).

Comment: It seems all your data updates onto object seriesList is not reflected onto values in SearchCustomAdapter. So...I think there are 2 options, one is to declare seriesList outside method onGetData (per my suggestion) or (good for testing) add a new method for SearchCustomAdapter for updating values in the Adapter, and you call the new method before notifyDataSetChanged call.

Comment: In onScrollComplete `pageNumber++;
         JsonHandling.getInstance().getJSONFromUrl(tvTitel.getText().toString(), tvYear.getText().toString(), iof, pageNumber);
      series.addAll(Serie.serieListFromJSON(this, JsonHandling.getInstance().getJSONArraySerieFromUrlTMDB(obj)));                 
      seriesList = series.toArray(new Serie[series.size()]);        
      lvSearch.setAdapter(new SearchCustomAdapter(this, seriesList));`
This part does work, but this should not be how i should use it.